# Fetching product categories in one row with product info

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 tables

```
products         categories       products_categories
------------     -------------    --------------------
product_id       category_id      product_id
product_title    category_title   category_id
```

Each product can belong to multiple categories as the db schema shows.
I join the three tables to get a listing of the three last inserted products.

```
SELECT p.product_id, 
      p.product_title, 
      c.category_id, 
      c.category_title 
FROM products p
INNER JOIN products_categories pc ON p.product_id = pc.product_id
INNER JOIN categories c ON pc.category_id = c.category_id GROUP BY p.product_id LIMIT 3
```

With the above query I get the products but with the first category that the product belongs to.

My question is, is it possible by modifying the query to get all the categories that each product belongs to, in one row along with the product info?

Or the only way is to execute another query for each product while fetching the list to get its categories?

Comment: Try GROUP BY pc.product_id instead. It does look correct though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.product_title,
       GROUP_CONCAT(c.category_title)
FROM products p
  INNER JOIN products_categories pc ON p.product_id = pc.product_id
  INNER JOIN categories c ON pc.category_id = c.category_id
GROUP BY p.product_id
```

See **GROUP_CONCAT** syntax [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: I can't test it right now but it looks like it should do the trick. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: @Khronos: hope it's the one for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Dont use "Group By". Then in your PHP Code group manually to product_id and collect all categories.

Comment: If I don't use the group by in sql, the query will return rows of the same product won't it? I want the last 3 different products.